# MongoDB concurency access

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, mongodb-query

On a standard mongodb installation, can we have concurrent access problems to a collection, if a user queries a document in a collection, exactly at the same time an administrator is editing this same document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the operations, different kind of locks are acquired.
You should read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/